# Angular Material 15 theming, list-theme

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular15, angular-material-theming

I have this error when I want to compile.
[image]

The error comes from the line

```
@include mat.list-theme($cdk-sidemenu-theme);
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to consult the documentation, but it didn't really help me.
I assume the error is from the parameter

I am using angular material 15.2.9